# How to select ifream using robot freamwork. (where Xpath, Id & Name isn't available)

Tags: robotframework

*** keyword***
frame should contain  Select from Google    xpath=//xpath=/html/frameset/frame[2]

Comment: xpath is always available if the iframe is part of the DOM. Also, please fix the formatting of the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the arguments in the wrong order. The first argument is a locator which represents the frame, and the second parameter is the expected text.

```
frame should contain  xpath=/html/frameset/frame[2]  Select from Google
```